# How to test a method that starts my application?

Tags: unit-testing, testing

I have a command line application written in a scripting language. The startup script does something like this:

```
import 'App'
app = new App()
app.run()
```

The `run()`method is responsible for instantiating all required objects and then actually starting the application:

```
import 'Artist', 'Song', 'Listener'

class App
  method run()
    artist = new Artist()
    song = new Song()
    listener = new Listener(artist, song)
    listener->listen()
  end
end
```

How can I write a test to make sure that `run()` is doing what it's supposed to do?

My initial thought was to add an optional argument so that I could pass a mock of `Listener` and expect `listen()` to be called, but it does not tell me if the actual Listener class will be instantiated correctly when running the application.

Another idea is to pass all the objects to `run()`, but then I would have to create them on the startup script, which I'd also have to test and the same problem arises.

Comment: "make sure that run() is doing what it's supposed to do". First describe what it's supposed to do?

Comment: @ClickBerry exactly what is in that code: instantiate the required objects and call `listen()`

Comment: @Schrute So what is `listen()` supposed to do?

Comment: @a.vector it doesn't really matter here, I have a separate test for the Listener class. What I'm not sure is if/how should I check that the `listen()` mehtod is being called on an object that was created correctly.

Comment: @Schrute ok, I would say don't test that objects are created collectedly.  I presume you test the constructor for the Listener class in its own unit tests.  Given that I would say you can trust the interpreter to construct your object correctly.  If you want to test that the interpreter can construct classes then you're testing your scripting language not your app.  If you want to functionally test the App class that would mean checking that `listen()` has done whatever it is supposed to do.  How you do that would in turn depend on what `listen()` is supposed to do.

Comment: @a.vector that makes sense, thanks. Post as an anwer, I'll wait a little longer, but I might accept that.

Comment: @Schrute, done.  My only other comment would be that behavioral testing is much more useful in the long term than strict unit testing.  There's a useful video on the subject [here](http://vimeo.com/68375232).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say don't test that objects are created correctly. I presume you test the constructor for the Listener class in its own unit tests. Given that I would say you can trust the interpreter to construct your object correctly. If you want to test that the interpreter can construct classes then you're testing your scripting language not your app.

If you want to functionally test the App class that would mean checking that `listen()` has done whatever it is supposed to do. How you do that would in turn depend on what `listen()` is supposed to do.

The other option is to expose what you need to test, of course there are lots of arguments about changing your code to make it more testable.  I won't go into them here.  But you could expose you Listener class in the App so you could query it in testing.

[Slight aside: some languages provide the means to expose properties to specific assemblies so that you don't have to expose properties publicly ([internalsvisibleto](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute(v=vs.110).aspx), I'm looking at you c#).]